# Error while applying same onClickListner to all items in custom list view [Android]

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio, onclicklistener

I created a custom list view and here is it's code. When I add onClickListener to the view then the toast is only made for ImageView only. When i Try to add same listener to other views(textview) then my app crashes. My custom list view class implements ONClickListener Please help me with this.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {


        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_demo6_1, null);

        ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.vImage);

        final TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.vName);
        final TextView write = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.vWrite);
        final TextView date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.vDate);

        name.setText(articleName[i]);
        write.setText(articleAuthor[i]);
        date.setText(articleDate[i]);

        view.setOnClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }

@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    Toast.makeText(context, name1.getText() + "\n" + write1.getText() + "\n" + date1.getText() + "" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are adding an onClickListener to "view", that should not be the way to add an on click listener to your view items, try this instead

```
@Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {


        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_demo6_1, null);

        ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.vImage);

        final TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.vName);
        final TextView write = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.vWrite);
        final TextView date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.vDate);

        name.setText(articleName[i]);
        write.setText(articleAuthor[i]);
        date.setText(articleDate[i]);

        name.setOnClickListener(this);
        write.setOnClickListener(this);
        date.setOnClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }

@Override
  public final void onClick(final View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
      case R.id.vName:
        nameClick(); // Create corresponding methods for each click, if its the same functionality just use the same method on all switch cases
        break;
      case R.id.vWrite:
        writeClick();
        break;
      case R.id.vDate:
        dateClick();
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }

private void nameClick(){
   Toast.makeText(context, name1.getText() + "\n" + write1.getText() + "\n" + date1.getText() + "" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to click on item/view, you can use:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { 
    //Your code here 
  } 
});
```

in your MainActivity/Host Activity. Or if you want to click each sub view inside the view then you should follow @andre answer.